# How to correctly sort by a column containing utf8 encoded data in MySql?

Tags: mysql, encoding

I have a table with names that are encoded as utf8. Displaying them is no problem since I can just call utf8_decode in php but the order of the names is wrong when I have mysql sort by that column.

For example:
I've got a name starting with "Ö" between the "A" and "B" names.

Edit 1: The column type is VARCHAR and collations of both the column and the table are (now) ut8_general_ci since they are multilingual. Previously they were latin1_swedish_ci if that matters.

Edit 2: I've found another problem. When I filled the table I mistakenly applied utf8_encode on the data even though it already was utf8. I've corrected it but the problem remains. But I don't have to call utf8_decode when I output it on my website...

Comment: What column type are you storing these in?

Comment: @Marcus Adams: I've updated the question

Answer (score 0):

You must define a UTF8 character sets and collation for the columns in the table that store UTF8 content.  The MySQL sort will then work properly based on your selected collation.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset.html

Answer (score 0):

In mysql, sorting is based on the column's collation. There are utf8 collations generally by natural language, if your data in one language you should try to use that collation. If you need to change the used collation at a query level use the [COLLATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-collate.html) keyword in the order by caluse, like:

```
SELECT k FROM t1 ORDER BY k COLLATE utf8_hungarian_ci;
```

If you don't know what to choose, use the `utf8_general_ci` collation ([demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1119/7)).

Comment: I've tried this but none of the collations i've tried sorts the contents correctly. The Ö is either before the A, after the A or at the very end of the alphabet.

Comment: The only collation that places `Ö` at the end of the a-z range is utf8_bin. Check this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1119/7

Answer (score 0):

If you are unhappy with how any of the built-in collations sort your data, then you can create your own collation:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/adding-collation.html